# How should this answer be handled?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, spam, first-post-review

On a [question about pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40575845/7571171) in Go, I came across this answer in review.
It's not about pointers or Go at all, but rather about *galvanized steel*:

[image]

At first, I thought about flagging this as spam, because it seemed to promote a product but I thought differently afterwards, because I was unsure as to whether to flag this as "spam" or maybe "not an answer" or "very low quality".

What would be the right approach here?

Comment: yeah .. flag as spam

Comment: If you suspect spam, take note of the username as they are almost always related to the brand in some way. In this case, the username is the name of the brand. If they are related, then flag as spam.

Comment: @LucianoFCastelfranchi thank you for the note. SO won't let me delete the question, but I will remove the link from my question.

Comment: You don't have to be Hawaiian to see that's spam. That's straight up military grade spam. That's so spammy I've got that clear jelly coming out of my ears.

Comment: According to the definition (exists to promote a product or service) it isn't spam though. It's completely useless, but not spam (at least according to that definition)...

Comment: It's spam because it's not a legitimate answer from someone attempting to answer the question correctly. It's blatant advertising so as such; it's spam.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One of the options you have at your disposal in the First Posts review queue is

> - **Flag** to notify the moderators of serious problems

This is spam, which *is* a serious problem on Stack Overflow and deserves to be flagged as such. It's spam because it satisfies the description of the spam flag option:

> Exists only to promote a product or service, does not disclose the author's affiliation.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think it perfectly illustrates my struggle: I was uncertain whether it could be really considered a *serious problem* and I didn't want to "overreact". I will accept the answer as soon as it will let me.

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow IMO it is more of an overreaction to ask this on meta. No need to involve the whole community, next time trust your instinct and raise a flag. If there is ambiguity, it should be handled fairly, the moderators are reasonable people